# How to fix broken Packages without internet access

Tags: networking, apt, dpkg

so i've uninstalled pihole on ubuntu 22.04.01 and removed the dependancy iproute2 which lead to no internet access - network-manager seems to be removed also but i didnt within the uninstall. After I've tried to manually add the packages to resolve the issue, it kept showing more and more dependancies for each package i add. I feel like this will go on in a loop.

Packages i added with `dpgk -i`:

> iproute2 libbpf0 network-manager (with dependancies via download * ) libndp0 libteamdctl0 isc-dhcp-client
> libdns-export1100 libisc-export1105 isc-dhcp-common

```
    Paketlisten werden gelesen… Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut… Fertig
Statusinformationen werden eingelesen… Fertig
Probieren Sie »apt --fix-broken install«, um dies zu korrigieren.
Die folgenden Pakete haben unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten:
 isc-dhcp-client : Hängt ab von: libdns-export1110 ist aber nicht installiert
 libdns-export1100 : Hängt ab von: libisc-export169 ist aber nicht installierbar
                     Hängt ab von: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) ist aber nicht installierbar
 libisc-export1105 : Hängt ab von: libssl1.1 (>= 1.1.0) ist aber nicht installierbar
 network-manager-openvpn : Hängt ab von: openvpn ist aber nicht installiert
 network-manager-pptp : Hängt ab von: ppp (< 2.4.9-2~) ist aber nicht installiert
                        Hängt ab von: ppp (>= 2.4.9-1+~) ist aber nicht installiert
                        Hängt ab von: pptp-linux ist aber nicht installiert
E: Unerfüllte Abhängigkeiten. Versuchen Sie »apt --fix-broken install« ohne Angabe eines Pakets (oder geben Sie eine Lösung an).
```

It's german but the issue is clear i think. At this point i can't install or uninstall packages. Net-Tools is not installed so i cannot go into recovery and configure eth0.

There is no Snapshot. Tell me if you need any more information.

**How do i return to regular/previous network configuration? Maybe with a Live USB of Ubuntu Desktop?**
**Should i just Reinstall Ubuntu and re-add the Data, Snaps etc.?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could reinstall, yes. However, it's fixable if you have a USB stick.

Either in a live environment or on another computer.

Boot live USB of Ubuntu desktop, grab the missing / removed packages via https://packages.ubuntu.com/ - for example, search for the package "iproute2" which takes us to https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=iproute2 -then click "Jammy" (the codename for 22.04) which leads us to https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/iproute2 then click your architecture "amd64" which leads to https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/amd64/iproute2/download where you can click a link on any mirror and it will download the deb.

Repeat that for every missing deb, then mount the internal disk, copy the debs over to a temporary folder on your home directory. Either do that directly if you're booted via the live environment, or copy onto a USB stick if not.

Reboot into the broken host machine, navigate to the folder with the debs in and `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.

Comment: That takes too long. I don't have time to do that. I download the first .deb file per your instructions, and then run a command of the form `apt install --simulate ./package-name.deb` (without `sudo`) iteratively which lists the missing dependencies for me as long as I run all the commands from the same directory. I run `ls *.deb` if I need to see what .deb files I downloaded.